# Show that $O_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ spans $\mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, analysis, orthogonal-matrices

It was given as an assignment problem.

> Given a real vector space $Y,$ let $T: \mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator such that $T$ restricted to $O_{3}(\mathbb{R}),$ the set of orthogonal matrices, is a constant mapping. Show that $T \equiv 0 .$ Can the result be extended to dimension $n \neq 3 ?$

---

My attempt:

Suppose the constant is c then, T(I)=c and T(-I) is c. $\implies$ T(0) = c $\implies$ c is 0.

So T is identically zero on $O_{3}(\mathbb{R})$.

If I show $O_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ spans $\mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$ then we are done.
I don't know where to start, I was trying to use SVD but couldn't succed.

Comment: With SVD, it suffices to show that every diagonal matrix is a linear combination of some orthogonal matrices. To begin, can you express $\operatorname{diag}(1,0,\ldots,0)$ as a linear combination of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: Oh got it. I can write it as $a*diag(1, 1,..., 1) + b*diag(1, -1,..., -1)$, where $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$. Then I've to use the fact that product of two orthogonal matrix is closed. Thanks.

Comment: @user1551 Am I right ?

Comment: Mostly. More precisely, if $A=USV^T$ is a SVD and $S$ can be expressed as a linear combination $\sum_ic_iQ_i$ of orthogonal matrices, then $A=\sum_ic_i(UQ_iV^T)$ is also a linear combination of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: We have not used n=3 anywhere, it means the result in the problem is true for any n?

Comment: @Sushant That is correct. The result is true for any $n$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another proof: we note that the function $\langle  A,B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$ defines an inner-product over $M_n(\Bbb R)$. It suffices to show that relative to this inner product, $O_n(\Bbb R)^\perp = \{0\}$.

Indeed, suppose that $A \in O_n(\Bbb R)^\perp$. The existence of the real [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) ensures that there exists a $U \in O_n(\Bbb R)$ for which $AU^T$ is positive semidefinite. However, since $A \in O_n(\Bbb R)^\perp$, we must have
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AU^T) = \langle A,U \rangle = 0.
$$
On the other hand, $AU^T$ is positive semidefinite, which means that $\operatorname{tr}(AU^T) \implies AU^T = 0$. Finally, $U$ is invertible, so $AU^T = 0 \implies A = 0$.

Comment: From this we can conclude $\mathcal{M}_3(\mathbb{R})$ = $O_{3}(\mathbb{R})^{\perp}$ $\oplus$ span($O_{3}(\mathbb{R})$) = {0} $\oplus$ span($O_{3}(\mathbb{R})$) = span($O_{3}(\mathbb{R})$). Am I right ?

Comment: @Sushant Yes, that's right.